# What is the fastest algorithm to solve an equality-constrained convex quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve the following convex problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^T Q x + px\\ \text{subject to} & Ax + b = 0\end{array}$$

which arises in the active set method for inequality/equality constrained quadratic optimization).

I have studied the conjugate gradient method, Newton's method with equality constraints, or solving the KKT matrix directly. Which one do you think is fastest? I need the algorithm to converge to high accuracy and be as fast as possible, and I have to notice that I am going to use it for polishing the solution obtained by the other solver so it may converge after a few iterations.

Comment: The size and sparsity of $A$ and $Q$ can make a huge difference.   How big are your matrices?  How dense are they?

Comment: @BrianBorchers The algorithm is going to be used mostly for high dimensional problems, so $A$ and $Q$ are big, and also there is no restriction on their density.

Comment: How big is big?  $N=1,000,000$? billions? thousands?

Comment: @BrianBorchers let's say around hundreds of thousands.

Comment: If $n$ is on the order of hundreds of thousands then simply storing $A$ and $Q$ as dense matrices is likely to be impractical and direct factorization of the KKT system isn't going to work either.  How do you plan to store $A$ and $Q$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, There is a system at the university, it's supposed to have enough memory, what about tens of thousands?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I mean it is going to be used for as much large $n$ that could fit into memory. I think tens of thousands might be a better estimate.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have implemented solving KKT system directly, but it is too slow, What should I do about this?

Comment: What software are you using to factor and solve the KKT system?  You'll want a highly optimized solver.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I'm using the built-in LDL function of Matlab, but I'm going to convert it to C++ so I will need another solver too, What solver do you recemmond?

Comment: The MATLAB solver that you're using is probably as efficient as you can get.  It's based on BLAS/LAPACK, which is what you should use for your C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a dense system, solving the KKT system gives the [solution](https://math189r.github.io/materials/section/constrained_optimization.pdf) as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & A^*\\A & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}^\star\\\boldsymbol{\nu}^\star
\end{bmatrix} = -\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{p}\\\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be solved accurately by an $LDL^*$ factor-solve method in [$\tfrac{1}{3}n^3 + 2n^2$](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-079-introduction-to-convex-optimization-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT6_079F09_lec15.pdf) flops. This is equivalent to running Newton for one step, so no need to compare there. Conjugate gradients is numerically unstable so would perform worse unless potentially your system was very large or sparse.

Comment: The system is not sparse but it could be very large, So you mean in this case It's better to solve the KKT system directly, right? Thanks.

Comment: I think the main takeaway is that you can reduce this to solving a system, so running the optimization version of CG won't give you anything. If you care about full accuracy and have a dense system, I'd argue that the LDL is the best you can do here. If the system dimension is 5000 this should take at most ~3 seconds. If you want a fast, quick approximation that is good but not great in terms of accuracy (seems like you don't want this) you might want to use traditional CG.

Comment: Is this linear system always solvable for positive semidefinite $Q$, or should I solve the perturbed one?

Comment: Regularization might help if the conditioning is terrible, but the system will always be solvable, yes. To see this, note that the KKT system is equivalent to optimality, and the restriction of the strongly convex objective to any subspace is still strongly convex and hence has a (unique) solution.

Comment: I’d suspect there’s an algebraic way to see this via Schur complements.

Comment: But it is not necessary strongly convex, it may only be convex, what about this case?

Comment: Ah I read “positive definite” — sorry. This might not have a solution. Consider $Q=0$, which isn’t bounded. In that case you might want to add a small perturbation to $Q$, which would add and effective 2-norm regularization to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If Q is not full rank, then the KKT matrix might be indefinite, although symmetric. In this case, you can't use CG directly.